# Solving an inequality for $n$ with 1) inverse trig and 2) disjointed $n$

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, trigonometry, inequality, convergence-divergence

So I'm given a question that essentially says "determine whether the following series converges, using the Integral Test":
$$
\sum_{n=5}^∞ \frac{\arctan(n)}{n^2+1}
$$
Say we let $f(n) = \frac{\arctan(n)}{n^2+1}$. One of the requirements for being able to use the Integral Test in the first place is that $f(n)$ be strictly decreasing on the relevant interval. But this wasn't immediately apparent to me just by looking at the function, so I wanted to see if this was *really* the case by solving the following inequality:
$$
f'(n)<0
$$
So I went on as follows:

$$
(f'(n)<0)=\left(\frac{1-(2n)(\arctan(n))}{(n^2+1)^2}<0\right)
$$

$$
=\left(1-(2n)(\arctan(n)<0\right)
$$

$$
=\left(1<(2n)(\arctan(n)\right)
$$

$$
=\left(\frac{1}{2}<(n)(\arctan(n))\right)
$$

$$
=\left(\frac{1}{2n}<\arctan(n)\right)
$$
And boom. I'm stuck. I have no idea how to proceed. I tried solving $f(n)>f(n+1)$ too, but was softlocked in a similar way. I even have the inkling that solving this is impossible without some computational trickery, but I want to be absolutely sure I'm not missing anything...

Is there really no way to show, on paper, that the function is decreasing?

Comment: You are making things hard for yourself. Consider the behaviour of $\arctan x$: it represents an angle between $-\frac\pi2$ and $\frac\pi2$. We then have that $\frac{\arctan n}{n^2+1} < \frac{\pi / 2}{n^2+1}$, which is clearly decreasing.

Comment: @Théophile well hold on a minute...your statement doesn't necessarily mean anything by itself. For example, take $g(n)=-20$. $g(n)<\frac{\pi/2}{n^2+1}$ is true, but $g(n)$ isn't decreasing; it's a constant line.

Comment: Since $n\ge 5$, $\arctan(n)>0$. The we have $0<\frac{\arctan(n)}{n^2+1}<\frac{\pi/2}{n^2+1}$. We could apply the Integral Test on the bigger fraction and conclude for the original.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just to complete your argument, starting with
$$1 < (2n)\arctan(n)$$
Since $\arctan(n)$ and $2n$ are strickly increasing funtion, we just need to show that it is true for $n=5$
$$(2(5))\arctan(5) = 13.73\ldots > 1$$

As said in the comment, you didn't need to do all that. $\arctan x$ is an angle between $-\frac\pi2$ and $\frac\pi2$ and, since $n\ge 5$, $\arctan(n) >0$. We have
$$0<\dfrac{\arctan(n)}{n^2+1} < \frac{\pi/2}{n^2+1}$$
The latter term is decreasing. We could apply the Intetgral test on $\frac{\pi/2}{n^2+1}$. Since the test will be conclusive, the smaller serie also converges.

Comment: 1) The top bit is clever! Is there a name for this technique that I can cite? As in something like "by *so and so* theorem..."?

2) The bottom bit ("As said in the comment....") I'm still puzzled on. Have a look at my response to Théophile's comment...

Comment: 1) there is no name for that technique. We just use what we know to be able to conclude. 2) I'll update my answer to make it clearer.

Comment: Excellent, makes sense now. Cheers!